# How can I calculate average of different values in each key of python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary. I want to calculate average of values for each key and print result so that the result shows key and associated average. The following code calculates mean but I don't know how to associate key with the average. My desired answer is Mean = {22:average1, 23:average2, 24:average3}.

```
          mydict = {22: [1, 0, 0, 1], 23: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 24: [3, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

          Mean =[float(sum(values)) / len(values) for key, values in 
          mydict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: Very close, just swap to a dictionary comprehension: `Mean = {key: float(sum(values)) / len(values) for key, values in dict.iteritems()}`

Comment: @roganjosh: Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a list comprehension. Use a dictionary comprehension to calculate the average of each list. You can also `from __future__ import division` to avoid having to use `float`:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> d = {22: [1, 0, 0, 1], 23: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 24: [3, 3, 2, 1, 0]}
>>> mean = {k: sum(v) / len(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
>>> mean
{22: 0.5, 23: 0.8, 24: 1.8}
```

Comment: Nifty bit... the future division!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hey, thanks! Actually, I didn't plan on using it until roganjosh pointed out the OP was using Python 2.7 :|

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right track. You just needed a dictionary comprehension instead of a list comp.

```
_dict = {22: [1, 0, 0, 1], 23: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 24: [3, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

mean = {key : float(sum(values)) / len(values) for key, values in _dict.iteritems()}
print(mean) 
{22: 0.5, 23: 0.8, 24: 1.8}
```

---

Notes:

1. `.iteritems` is replaced with `.items` in python3
2. *(Statutory Warning)* Do not use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin class with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you @COLDSPEED. Trust me I didn't know I could accept the answers, I was always trying to vote answers but since I have small reputation I could not.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Python 3.4+

```
>>> from statistics import mean    # Python 3.4+
>>> d = {22: [1, 0, 0, 1], 23: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 24: [3, 3, 2, 1, 0]}
>>> {k:mean(v) for k,v in d.items()}
{22: 0.5, 23: 0.8, 24: 1.8}
>>>
```