# Creating a new dictionary with same key and values averaged from another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an existing dictionary called StudentGrad that has the following data type:

```
('Aditya','male','senior'):[0.83,0.87,0.82,0.83],
('Varun','male','senior'):[0.76,0.86,0.88,0.79],
('Shantanu','male','senior'):[0.79,0.81,0.78,0.78],
```

I want to create a new dictionary called studentAvg that has the same keys, but returns an average grade for the values:

```
('Aditya','male','senior'):[0.84],
('Varun','male','senior'):[0.82],
('Shantanu','male','senior'):[0.79],
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Thanks!

Comment: Why are your averages in single element lists instead of just a number?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Does [How can I calculate average of different values in each key of python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082236/how-can-i-calculate-average-of-different-values-in-each-key-of-python-dictionary) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension and a custom function for averaging :

```
d1 = {('Aditya','male','senior'):[0.83,0.87,0.82,0.83],
('Varun','male','senior'):[0.76,0.86,0.88,0.79],
('Shantanu','male','senior'):[0.79,0.81,0.78,0.78],
}
def average(list_values):
  "let's assume you want an arithmetic mean"
  return sum(list_values) / len(list_values)
d2 = {k:average(val) for k, val in d1.items()}
```

And if you really want a list of the average (as stated in the question) :

```
d2 = {k:[average(val)] for k, val in d1.items()}
```

Comment: Why not use [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)??

Comment: @wwii There a many ways of doing it. But with this method at least (I think), you are better understanding the mechanisms of python. (Personnally, I'm a fan of pandas and that would be the way I'd do it :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
x  = {('Aditya','male','senior'):[0.83,0.87,0.82,0.83],
('Varun','male','senior'):[0.76,0.86,0.88,0.79],
('Shantanu','male','senior'):[0.79,0.81,0.78,0.78]}

def average(data):
    sum = 0
    for elem in data:
        sum+=elem
    result = sum/len(data)
    return result

y = {}

for elem in x:
    y[elem] = average(x[elem])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
studentAvg = {
   ('Aditya','male','senior'):sum(studendGrad["('Aditya','male','senior')"])/len(studendGrad["('Aditya','male','senior')"]),
   ('Varun','male','senior'):sum(studentGrad["(Varun','male','senior')"])/len(studentGrad["('Varun','male','senior')"]),
   ('Shantanu','male','senior'):sum(studentGrad["('Shantanu','male','senior')"]/len(studentGrad["('Shantanu','male','senior')"])
}
```